# GORM Criteria Join

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given the following classes:

```
class Abc {
    String course 
    Date startDate
}

Class Xyz {
    Abc abc
    Date xyzInDate 
}
```

The end user will input provide the `course` and `startDate` and  I need to find all `Abc` classes that match the `course` and the `startDate` matches the `xyzInDate` from the associated `Xyz` class.

Comment: Are you looking for all objects where `abc.startDate == xyz.xyzInDate` or just objects where both dates match a given value?

Comment: User input `course, startDate` . Then i want all `Abc(AbcList)`for input(`course, startDate` .) and if any data where `abc.startDate == xyz.xyzInDate` and `xyz.abc inlist(AbcList)`